# Clean boot to Windows when using Boot Camp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, driver

I was experiencing issues trying to update Windows 7 to SP1, and according to Windows Support I should do a 'clean boot' to Windows. My issue is that I'm running Windows on my 2009 MacBook, through Boot Camp. While following the steps they provided me, [How to perform a clean boot in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135?Ocid=1.%20Owned%20NA%20(Reactive)_Social_TWITTER_WindowsSupport_20150818_223740763&linkId=16378565), I noticed that when disabling services I'll be disabling drivers that I think are necessary for Windows to function on my Mac.

[image]

Will booting with these services disabled affect booting/not allow me to boot to Windows and/or OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as the KB Article suggests.  If there is an issue you can always boot to Safe Mode and reenable the disabled Drivers, Services, etc.

That said, keep in mind that when first installing Windows via the Boot Camp Assistant that Windows on Boot Camp installs and first runs without any Boot Camp Drivers installed.  So, I see no issues with disabling any and all non-Microsoft Drivers, Services, etc. in order to troubleshoot an issue or clean boot Windows.

**Edit:** I should have also said, I have done this numerous times, in the past, on PC's as well as Mac's and was never not able to boot because of disabling non-Microsoft Drivers, Services, etc.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know if it works!